# How To Do Something For Every Particular Sheet Edited?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to check for example if 'Sheet1' is active and someone edit it then do something, if  'Sheet2' is active and someone edit it then do the other thing. Here's the example of a code but with this code if someone edit in any sheet it will load all the codes from respective sheet and its kinda waste.

Is there a way to check if someone edit in particular sheet? Your response will be apreciated :)

Here's the sample code:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const mean= ss.getRange('C2:C');
  mean.setFormula("=SUM((A2+B2)/2)");
  
  var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  const total= ss1.getRange('E2:E');
  total.setFormula("=SUM(A2+B2+C2+D2)");
}
```

Comment: I proposed a modified script. Could you please confirm it. But I'm worry whether I could correctly understand about your goal. So at first, can you confirm whether my understanding for your goal is correct. If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize. At that time, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Comment: Yupp Its perfectly work! Thank you so musch!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to run the script for each sheet when the sheet is edited.

In this case, you can select the script using the event object of the OnEdit event as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  var sheetName = sheet.getSheetName();
  if (sheetName == "Sheet1") {
    const mean = sheet.getRange('C2:C');
    mean.setFormula("=SUM((A2+B2)/2)");
  } else if (sheetName == "Sheet2") {
    const total = sheet.getRange('E2:E');
    total.setFormula("=SUM(A2+B2+C2+D2)");
  }
}
```

- In this modification, when "Sheet1" is edited, `const mean = sheet.getRange('C2:C'); mean.setFormula("=SUM((A2+B2)/2)");` is run. When "Sheet2" is edited, `const total = sheet.getRange('E2:E'); total.setFormula("=SUM(A2+B2+C2+D2)");` is run.

#### References:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)